# minimum number of swap two adjacent element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How to find the minimum number of swaps two adjacent element of an array so that no element is equal to its index.

i.e.,

```
array[i]!=i
```

example =>

```
I/P = [2,1,3]
O/P = 1
```

Comment: Looks like how many swaps does bubble-sort make on this.

Comment: ya but all element follows (arr[i] != i)

Comment: Can the array have duplicate values?

Comment: @trincot no all are distinct and unordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call an element that is equal to its position a "wrong" element.

Let  be the number of wrong elements. The goal is to reduce  to zero.

### Analysis

This problem would have been more complex if duplicate values were allowed, but given they are distinct, we can observe the following:

- A swap is only useful if it reduces . If  is not decreased by it, there is no way to take benefit from that swap in future swaps.
- If a swap reduces  by 2, it may still not be an optimal swap. For example, if in [1,2,3,4] we first swap (2,3), then we will need 2 more swaps to bring  to zero, while this can be solved using just *two* swaps. We can avoid this by starting with the *first* pair (or *last* pair,...) when dealing with a group of adjacent wrong elements.

### Algorithm

- If the array has only one element and it is wrong -- i.e. the input is [1] -- then there is no solution possible.
- Iterate through the array from left to right.
- When arriving at a wrong element, perform a single swap with the next element if there is one, otherwise swap with the previous one.
- Return the number of swaps made.

### Improvement

We can actually improve on this, and only *count* the swaps, but not actually perform them. In that case we must skip the next element when we count a swap of the current element with the next. This is to avoid we would count another swap for it when it is also bad, as the current swap would also resolve that. On the other hand, this swap never *makes* the next one bad, so when counting this swap we can safely skip checking the next element.

### Implementation

Here is a JavaScript snippet that returns the result for several inputs:

```js
function countSwaps(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 1 && arr[0] == 1) return Infinity; // No solution
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == i + 1) { // It is a bad element
            count++;
            // Skip the next element, because:
            // If it is bad, it is resolved by this swap
            // If it is good, it cannot turn bad by this swap
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(countSwaps([2,1,3]));  // 1
console.log(countSwaps([6,2,3,4,5,1]));  // 2
console.log(countSwaps([5,2,3,4,1]));  // 2
console.log(countSwaps([4,3,2,1,5]));  // 1
console.log(countSwaps([2]));  // 0
console.log(countSwaps([]));  // 0
console.log(countSwaps([1]));  // Infinity
```